# select n number of element from an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is given array of `size > n` , we need to select `n` number of element from an array.

For example : array contain 112 element and n = 50, so select 50 number such that distance between every two selected number is more or less equal (equal distance is not possible of course except for `size%n == 0` ).

If anyone suggest any idea that would work .

```
Example : 

array = 1 2 3 4 5
n = 1
output : 1  or any another number depending on proposed algo.
n = 2
output : 1 3 or  2 4 or 1 4...
n = 3
output : 1 3 5
n = 4
output : 1 3 4 5 or 1 2 4 5 
n = 5 : 
output 1 2 3 4 5
```

Basically in case of n=1,2,4 there are more then one possible combination so I need to devise an algo which would pick numbers in uequally distributed manner.

Comment: difference or distance in the array?

Comment: any more restrictions? ... for example such as n NOT consecutive elements?

Comment: @YSC this is distance .

Comment: @fritzone I didn't get you?

Comment: I don't get it. `size = 4`, `n = 3`, `array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }`. How would you do?

Comment: @EmptyData I'm unable to understand the problem from the description given above. Please consider adding an example and give a more clear description of the problem, so that we can help.

Comment: Quit deficult to understand your question. Please explain more.

Comment: @blazs  updated description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be dividing the number of elements by the number of desired elements in the selection in floating point, and using rounding to determine the index:

```
double dist = ((double)size) / n;
int *res = new int[n];
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    res[i] = orig[round(dist*i)];
}
```

For your example of `112` and `50` the value of `dist` would be `2.24` and the sequence of indexes selected from the array would be

```
0   0
1   2
2   4
3   7
4   9
5   11
......
45  101
46  103
47  105
48  108
49  110
```

Comment: How, you _did_ get the question. Its the best answer, rounding at the last moment.